# Dispose widget when navigating to new route

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two screens in my app.

Screen A runs a computationally expensive operation while opened, and properly disposes by cancelling animations/subscriptions to the database when `dispose()` is called to prevent memory leaks.

From Screen A, you can open another screen (Screen B).

When I use `Navigator.pushNamed`, Screen A remains in memory, and `dispose()` is not called, even though Screen B is now shown.

Is there a way to force disposal of Screen A when it is not in view?

Example code where first route is never disposed:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstRouteState createState() => _FirstRouteState();
}

class _FirstRouteState extends State<FirstRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Open route'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Never called
    print("Disposing first route");
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Text('Go back!'),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Disposing second route");
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to dispose the previous route. Instead you'll want to pause the heavy operation while it's hidden. See RouteAware

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know it's a bit late but I think you should override the `deactivate` method. Since we are changing the page we are not actually destroying it, that's why the `dispose` isn't being called.

If you'd like more information [this page lists](https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/12/flutter-lifecycle-widgets.html) the lifecycle of the stateful widgets.

From the link:

> 'deactivate()' is called when State is removed from the tree, but it might be
> reinserted before the current frame change is finished. This method exists basically
> because State objects can be moved from one point in a tree to another.

Comment: This must be the selected answer AFAIK

Comment: Link is dead :sob:

Comment: This doesn't work, I've tested, when I called navigator.push, deactive function was not called

Answer (score 12):

call `Navigator.pushReplacement` when routing between first and second screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstRouteState createState() => _FirstRouteState();
}

class _FirstRouteState extends State<FirstRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Open route'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Never called
    print("Disposing first route");
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FirstRoute()),
          );
        },
        child: Text('Go back!'),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Disposing second route");
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Try this

Comment: Tried this but it breaks the navigation flow. You can't swipe back on iOS or press back button on Android to go back to the previous page.

Comment: ok, you want to restrict the android back button or want the functionality to back to the first screen?

Comment: I wanted it to behave normally (normal back button) with disposal of the first screen.

Comment: Great for login redirects!

Answer (score 5):

In new versions of flutter `deactivate` won't be called when you push a new widget on top of another widget. Also there is an open issue related to this topic on flutter's github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50147

The best way to handle this issue is to add `RouteObserver<PageRoute>` to your material app and override `didPushNext` and `didPopNext` functions.

There is a very helpful medium article related to this topic which you can find here: https://medium.com/koahealth/how-to-track-screen-transitions-in-flutter-with-routeobserver-733984a90dea

As Article said create your own `RouteAwareWidget`, you can add these two call backs to the fields of the widget:
`didPopNext`
`didPushNext`

```dart
class RouteAwareWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback? didPopNext;
  final VoidCallback? didPushNext;

  const RouteAwareWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    this.didPopNext,
    this.didPushNext,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RouteAwareWidget> createState() => RouteAwareWidgetState();
}

class RouteAwareWidgetState extends State<RouteAwareWidget> with RouteAware {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {}

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    dPrint('didPopNext');
    widget.didPopNext == null ? null : widget.didPopNext!();
    super.didPopNext();
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    dPrint('didPushNext');
    widget.didPushNext == null ? null : widget.didPushNext!();
    super.didPushNext();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.child;
}
```

Create a global `RouteObserver<PageRoute>` and add it to your material app:

```dart
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

MaterialApp(
     navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     routes: _routes,
)
```

then in your routes you should wrap your routes with `RouteAwareWidget` and add custom functions that you want:

```dart
  final _routes = {
    HomePage.routeName: (context) => RouteAwareWidget(
          child: const HomePage(),
          didPushNext: () => sl<CameraBloc>().add(Dispose()),
          didPopNext: () => sl<CameraBloc>().add(Init()),
        ),
    MyQuestions.routeName: (context) => const RouteAwareWidget(
          child: MyQuestions(),
        ),
};
```

`didPushNext` will be called when you push a widget on top of HomePage and `didPopNext` will be called when you pop the last widget above HomePage.

Answer (score 2):

A light weight solution for a single route case is using a callback function triggered from the `SecondRoute`.

Trigger the callback from the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` within the `initState()` on the `SecondRoute`

More information on WidgetsBinding and when they run can be found here: [Flutter: SchedulerBinding vs WidgetsBinding](https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-schedulerbinding-vs-widgetsbinding-149c71cb607f#:%7E:text=addPostFrameCallback%20is%20run%20during%20a,still%20executed%20during%20the%20frame.).

> WidgetsBinding & SchedulerBinding will be printed only once as we called it initState(), but it will be called when build method finished it’s rendering.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstRoute({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstRoute> createState() => _FirstRouteState();
}

class _FirstRouteState extends State<FirstRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Screen A')),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text('Go to Screen B'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondRoute(_callbackFn),
              ),
            );
            _secondRouteDone();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _callbackFn() {
    print("Widget B Loaded, Free up memory, dispose things, etc.");
  }

  _secondRouteDone() {
    print("SecondRoute Popped, Reinstate controllers, etc.");
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function() notifyIsMountedFn;

  const SecondRoute(this.notifyIsMountedFn, {super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondRoute> createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Notify FirstRoute after paint
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      widget.notifyIsMountedFn();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Screen B')),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Navigator.pushReplacement(), if using MaterialPageRoute, then setting

```
maintainState:false
```

will ensure that dispose() is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pushReplacementNamed** method. For reference : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34950753)

Answer (score -1):

Not only to call 'deactivate()' but also to use 'Navigator.pushReplacement()' for page moving is necessary. Not working if you are using 'Navigator.push()'.