# RouteObserver use and Widget disposing when navigatin to another route with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, firebase-admob

I'm currently developing an app which uses ads.
I've created an  Adbanner  for testing in the main view.
In the main view i have a lot of buttons that send the user to other routes. Most of this buttons are in another classes and used elsewhere inside the app. I know that to dismiss or dispose the banner i just need to call `Dispose()` or `Dismiss()`.
My problem is that i'm lookin for a way to dismiss or dispose the bannerAd on the `Navigator.push()`
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165705/flutter-how-the-navigatorobserver-class-works) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140674/dispose-widget-when-navigating-to-new-route) that doesnt answer my question.
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

Comment: dispose->when you forced the object to be destroyed  and Dismiss->when you "hide" it

Comment: Check if the object is exists in the current context and in that case dispose it since i'll have a new ad on the new page eg. MainPage->OldAd->push->Dispose(OldAd)->newPage->NewAd