# Method 'dispose' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: dispose()) - Push.Navigator

Tags: flutter

I added in last page of my app a button to move back to the previous page - expecting to refresh the complete app or page.

```
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashPage()), // this mymainpage is your page to refresh
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
        );
```

I receive the below error message when pressed.

> ═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
> The method 'dispose' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: dispose()
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

What do I need to place in the Dispose widget to avoid calling null.

```
  DateFormat format = DateFormat('dd/MM');
  List<bool> flips = [false, false, false, false];
  List tarots = [];
  List unLockCard = [];
  BannerAd _bannerAd;

@override
void dispose() {
  _bannerAd.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

I looked into this solution [Dispose widget when navigating to new route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140674/dispose-widget-when-navigating-to-new-route) but can not apply.

Comment: are you using null-safety?

Comment: _bannerAd is set when entering the dispose method?

Comment: the method _bannerAd has a null safety

Comment: how  and where did you assign data on `_bannerAd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a situation that the banner has not loaded so tying to dispose it when its null will throw an error. You can add a condition check before you dispose

```
@override
void dispose() {
 if(_bannerAd != null)
 {
   _bannerAd.dispose();
 }
  super.dispose();
}
```

if you are using null safety you can declare banner ad like

```
BannerAd? _bannerAd;
```

and dispose it like

```
_bannerAd?.dispose();
```