# Riverpod: stop watching Firestore collection while screen is not visible

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I am writing a cross-platform app in Flutter, with Riverpod for managing state, and Firestore as the back-end database. This question explores one of the alternatives I proposed in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452269/how-to-subscribe-to-an-entire-collection-and-a-document-within-it-simultaneously).

I'm using Riverpod's `StreamProvider` to subscribe to a certain Firestore collection, and a provider family to listen to individual documents within that collection.

```dart
final collectionProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose((ref) => Firestore.instance.collection("my_collection").snapshots());
final documentProviderFamily =
    StreamProvider.autoDispose.family<DocumentSnapshot, String>((ref, documentId) 
        => Firestore.instance.collection("my_collection").doc(documentId).snapshots());
```

I have a page (a widget) that listens to the collection and shows some info about each document in a ListView:

```dart
CollectionPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  ...

  void build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final snapshot = ref.watch(collectionProvider);

    ...
  }
}
```

If the user clicks on a ListTile, a details page (a widget) is opened, with `Navigator.of(context).push(...)`, showing detailed info about the corresponding document.

**Importantly, this details page also needs to update in real-time**, so just passing it the current object/document snapshot held by the collection page doesn't work. Instead, this widget watches that individual document from Firestore:

```dart
DocumentDetailsPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  ...

  final String documentId;

  void build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final snapshot = ref.watch(documentProviderFamily(documentId));

    ...
  }
}
```

Suppose we have one of these details page open. Since the navigator stack still contains the CollectionPage widget, the subscription to the collection stream is still active. So, whenever the document in question is updated, two reads will occur on Firestore: one for the collection subscription and another one for the single document subscription. (I found this out by using the Firestore emulator and looking at the requests tab.)

Since the CollectionPage is not visible, the former update is wasteful. A single update to the document is causing duplicate reads of the same document (being charged accordingly in Firestore). Ideally I would like to cancel the subscription to the entire collection when the details page is opened, and re-start it when the details page is popped.

In riverpod terms: how do I temporarily un-watch the provider while the widget is not visible and start watching again when it becomes visible again?

I've read [Dispose widget when navigating to new route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140674/dispose-widget-when-navigating-to-new-route), and it seems this kind of behaviour (cancelling the listener when the screen is not visible) should go into the `deactivate()` method of the widget, but then again I don't know how to make Riverpod do this, and the Q&A mentions that this method is not reliable anyways.

Comment: the question is, why do you still need to rewatch a single document after watching the whole collection? It doesn't make sense. You should just be passing the object to another page and not rewatching so that if you go back to your collection, you don't need to rewatch your entire collection and be charged with another collection reads.

Comment: Presuming you're running with the latest stable riverpod, look at ref.invalidate.

Comment: @john Because that document might change while the page is open, and the page should update in real time. Your suggestion doesn't take this into account. An alternative would be to use the same stream of the entire collection in the details page, and make the page select the document it wants out of the collection, as I suggested in the linked question. However this complicates the code and puts more load on the client.