# How to dispose stateful widgets in flutter before navigating to a different screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a stateful widget (a persistent search bar) in my flutter web application and when a search query gets submitted, I am navigating to a different screen with `context.go(...)`. The new screen draws the search bar again (as the idea is to persist it on top throughout the lifecycle of the application).

I noticed that the search bar keeps using more and more memory and eventually slows down the whole app. My guess is that the dispose method never gets called on it and because a new instance of a search bar gets created every time a route is pushed, it keeps on increasing in size. What is the flutter way to avoid this problem and make sure my stateful widget is fully disposed before a new screen gets created?

My widget looks like:

```
class PersistentSearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersistentSearchBar({super.key});

  @override
  State<PersistentSearchBar> createState() => _PersistentSearchBarState();
}

class _PersistentSearchBarState extends State<PersistentSearchBar> {
  List<SearchSuggestion> _searchSuggestions = [];
  List<SearchSuggestion> _initialSearchSuggestions = [];

  void _loadData() async {
    List<SearchSuggestion> searchSuggestions =
        await _addSearchSuggestionsFromJson();

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _searchSuggestions = searchSuggestions;
        _initialSearchSuggestions = searchSuggestions;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingSearchBar(
      ....
      onQueryChanged: (searchTerm) {
        _searchSuggestions = filterSearchSuggestions(...);
      }
      onSubmitted: (query) {
        context.go(Uri(
            path: '/results',
            queryParameters: {'title': '', 'userQuery': query}).toString());
      },
    );
}
```

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION:  consider overriding `deactivate()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59603724/421195